# Selecting an enum for a payment transaction

Tags: java, android, finance, enum

I'm writing a small Android application that deals with payments and, in my function that handles transactions, I need to translate a number of installments (1-12) and whether or not it has interest (0-1) into the de facto objects for those of the SDK I'm using.

Right now I have a switch that looks like the following:

```
InstalmentTransactionEnum install = InstalmentTransactionEnum.ONE_INSTALMENT;
//TODO: Implement interest
switch (installments) {
    case "1":
        install = InstalmentTransactionEnum.ONE_INSTALMENT;
        break;
    case "2":
        install = InstalmentTransactionEnum.TWO_INSTALMENT_NO_INTEREST;
        break;
    case "3":
        install = InstalmentTransactionEnum.THREE_INSTALMENT_NO_INTEREST;
        break;
    case "4":
        install = InstalmentTransactionEnum.FOUR_INSTALMENT_NO_INTEREST;
        break;
    case "5":
        install = InstalmentTransactionEnum.FIVE_INSTALMENT_NO_INTEREST;
        break;
    case "6":
        install = InstalmentTransactionEnum.SIX_INSTALMENT_NO_INTEREST;
        break;
    case "7":
        install = InstalmentTransactionEnum.SEVEN_INSTALMENT_NO_INTEREST;
        break;
    case "8":
        install = InstalmentTransactionEnum.EIGHT_INSTALMENT_NO_INTEREST;
        break;
    case "9":
        install = InstalmentTransactionEnum.NINE_INSTALMENT_NO_INTEREST;
        break;
    case "10":
        install = InstalmentTransactionEnum.TEN_INSTALMENT_NO_INTEREST;
        break;
    case "11":
        install = InstalmentTransactionEnum.ELEVEN_INSTALMENT_NO_INTEREST;
        break;
    case "12":
        install = InstalmentTransactionEnum.TWELVE_INSTALMENT_NO_INTEREST;
        break;
}
stoneTransaction.setInstalmentTransactionEnum(install);
```

Now this is **without** me having implemented interest which in this method would require another massive switch statement where `install` would be equal to `TWO_INSTALLMENT_WITH_INTEREST` and so on.

My thinking is that there *must* be a smarter way of doing this that doesn't involve an if statement to check the `interest` variable (a boolean) and the massive switch for `installments`. What is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful, but learning to use `enum.valueOf(String)` effectively will be useful as a general programmer, even if it doesn't help this particular scenario.

Comment: Suppose that we end up selecting the appropriate enum — _then_ what? In other words, why do you want an enum in the first place?

Comment: So this is the library hmms? http://stone-pagamentos.github.io/sdk-android/#provedor-de-transao

Comment: @200_success I get the appropriate enum and pass it on to a transaction object of the SDK and continue to do a transaction

Comment: @h.j.k., yep that's the one

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're using the wrong tool for the job.

If there's ever going to be a loan that I will pay an amount to every week for 2 years, you're gonna have to write a script to generate the code for you, because doing it by hand would suck. You'd have to write code for 204 different enum values, including the switch cases.

If you had to map months to strings, you could have given your enums values, e.g.

```
enum Month {
    JANUARY(1, "January", "JAN"),
    FEBRUARI(2, "February", "FEB"),
    ...

    private int number;
    private String name;
    private String shorthandName;
    Month(int month, String fullName, String shortName){
        number = month;
        name = fullName;
        shorthandName = shortName;
    }
    //add getters....
}
```

Like that.

But what you have here is more like an object. You have two values to keep track of, **and they are not related.** This doesn't lend itself to an enumeration as you'll need to create each combination by hand.

For that, I recommend using value objects. An example of a value object is a String. It's an immutable object of which you cannot change the value.

So consider making a class like so:

```
class InstallmentTransaction {
    private final int installments;
    private final boolean interest;

    private static final Map<Integer, Map<Boolean, InstallmentTransaction>> instances = new HashMap<>();
    private static final Object lockObject = new Object();

    private InstallmentTransaction(int installments, boolean interest)
    {
        this.installments = installments;
        this.interest = interest;
    }

    public static InstallmentTransaction getInstance(int installments, boolean interest){
        synchronized(lockObject){
            Map<Boolean, InstallmentTransaction> map = instances.get(installments);
            if(map == null){
                map = new HashMap<>();
                instances.put(installments, map);
            }
            InstallmentTransaction instance = map.get(interest);
            if(instance == null){
                instance = new InstallmentTransaction(installments, interest);
                map.put(interest, instance);
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    //getters go here
}
```

I didn't implement the full thing, that's something you'll have to do, but this will give you the benefit of object equality combined with the ability to reference instances (`getInstance(12, false)`).

I also opted for `Integer` here, because that's the format you store numbers in. Even if the API only exposes Strings, that doesn't mean you are stuck using Strings. `""+int` will give you a String, and `Integer.parseInt("")` will give you an integer.

`synchronized` is used to prevent there being two threads both calling `getInstance` at the same time and creating two objects for the same values.

---

The upsides of this approach are that it automatically supports all values of installments and interest.

The downside is that if you have a lot of values, you risk filling up your memory with all of them. You don't have this, though, as right now it's going to be 24 values (12 months * 2). For Android development, it might not even matter - apps don't have the same active duration as server applications do.

Comment: While trying to implement this (and I just copied and pasted to get started) I got an [error](https://gist.github.com/bemeurer/4cf979cbb2ee47f923d3)

Comment: @BernardMeurer https://ideone.com/RBwKvN - I copy and pasted into ideone and I get 0 errors. Looks like you're doing something wrong. What does the line you're using look like?

Comment: Figured, when I copied it the private constructor part was still missing :)

Comment: Why are you reimplementing `enum` with a static flyweight cache and losing the compile-time integrity offered by `enum`s?

Comment: @corsiKa see answer: because if you have to expand to cover `ONE_HUNDRED_AND_FOUR_INSTALMENT_NO_INTEREST`, something has gone wrong. That's the situation I'm describing at the top: pay per week for 2 years. I'll expand the explanation, though.

Comment: I'd add that the mere presence of a `switch` is a *code smell* (searchable term).  A code smell is not wrong, per se, but suggests an opportunity for improvement.  Any time you see a `switch` or a series of `else if` statements, it suggests that your code is not very OO.

Answer (score 6):

There is a better way indeed, which is to have the `installments` value as an attribute of each enumeration value.

An as example, we can simply consider 2 of those enum values. The idea is to construct each value with the given installment `String`. Then, we can create a look-up method that selects the right enumeration from a given value.

```
public enum InstalmentTransactionEnum {

    ONE_INSTALMENT("1"),
    TWO_INSTALMENT_NO_INTEREST("2");

    private final String installments;

    InstalmentTransactionEnum(String installments) {
        this.installments = installments;
    }

    public static InstalmentTransactionEnum forInstallments(String installments) {
        for (InstalmentTransactionEnum value : InstalmentTransactionEnum.values()) {
            if (value.installments.equals(installments)) {
                return value;
            }
        }
        return ONE_INSTALMENT;
    }

}
```

In your application code, you can then simply have:

```
InstalmentTransactionEnum install = InstalmentTransactionEnum.forInstallments(installments);
```

without the need of any `switch` statements.

---

If you intend to do this operation quite often, you could further create a `Map<String, InstalmentTransactionEnum>` that will serve as the loop-up base:

```
public enum InstalmentTransactionEnum {

    ONE_INSTALMENT("1"),
    TWO_INSTALMENT_NO_INTEREST("2");

    private static final Map<String, InstalmentTransactionEnum> LOOKUP;

    static {
        LOOKUP = new HashMap<>();
        for (InstalmentTransactionEnum value : InstalmentTransactionEnum.values()) {
            LOOKUP.put(value.installments, value);
        }
    }

    private final String installments;

    InstalmentTransactionEnum(String installments) {
        this.installments = installments;
    }

    public static InstalmentTransactionEnum forInstallments(String installments) {
        InstalmentTransactionEnum value = LOOKUP.get(installments);
        return value == null ? ONE_INSTALMENT : value;
    }

}
```

or, if you're using Java 8, you could further simplify this using the Stream API to construct the look-up map and `getOrDefault` to return the default value:

```
public enum InstalmentTransactionEnum {

    ONE_INSTALMENT("1"),
    TWO_INSTALMENT_NO_INTEREST("2");

    private static final Map<String, InstalmentTransactionEnum> LOOKUP =
        Arrays.stream(InstalmentTransactionEnum.values())
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(v -> v.installments, v -> v));

    private final String installments;

    InstalmentTransactionEnum(String installments) {
        this.installments = installments;
    }

    public static InstalmentTransactionEnum forInstallments(String installments) {
        return LOOKUP.getOrDefault(installments, ONE_INSTALMENT);
    }

}
```

Comment: Very nice! How would I add the `WITH_INTEREST` options though?

Comment: @BernardMeurer By adding more enum values with their respective `installments` value. I've just provided a sample with 2 values but you can extend it to any.

Comment: The upside of this approach is that you can have all your values in one place with compile time checking. The downside is the case I mentioned - where installments are in "weeks" and the loan takes multiple years - enjoy writing 200+ enum values. It depends on your expected use-case.

Comment: @Tunaki, The issue is that, lets say, a 3 month payment both with and without interest will have `installments` set to `3`, but the second variable `interest` will shift from 0 to 1

Comment: @BernardMeurer Ha well that is something that you didn't mention in your post. But the idea is the same: have `InstalmentTransactionEnum` this time take 2 values in the constructor: the `installments` and the `interest`. And in the look-up phase, you search with the right `installments` and `interest`. The look-up Map in this case would be `Map<String, Map<Integer, InstalmentTransactionEnum>>`.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you can use a `Map<String, InstalmentTransactionEnum>`

```
install  = map.get(installments);
```

However why the enum in the first place? You can simply parse the string as an int with `Integer.parseString` and use the return value directly.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming if we're talking about the [same SDK](http://stone-pagamentos.github.io/sdk-android/#provedor-de-transao), then perhaps the worry that you'll need to support 100+ `enum`s is unnecessary... or you should *really consider switching SDKs* if you/the library developers do get to that stage.

`enum`s values are *ordered* (hence the [`ordinal()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal--) method), and the ordering the SDK uses seem to be:

```
0 -> ONE_INSTALMENT
1 -> TWO_INSTALMENT_NO_INTEREST
...
11 -> TWELVE_INSTALMENT_NO_INTEREST
12 -> TWO_INSTALMENT_WITH_INTEREST
..
22 -> TWELVE_INSTALMENT_WITH_INTEREST
```

Unless the SDK *explicitly discourages* the reliance on the `enum` ordering, usually it's reliable enough to do so as changing the ordering will potentially have other complications (e.g. iterating through an `EnumSet` or `EnumMap` will change too).

That means it should be possible for you to derive the appropriate mapping by:

1. Convert `"1"` into an `int` (or not do the conversion if you started out as an `int`).
2. Consider if you need to apply installments or not.
3. Math.

```
boolean hasInterest = /* determine if interest is required? */;
// assumes a one-month installment does not have interest
int index = (Integer.parseInt(installments) - 1) + (hasInterest ? 0 : 11);
InstalmentTransactionEnum result = InstalmentTransactionEnum.values()[index];
```

Comment: Bad generic advice (math hax like this is not very extensible) but awesome specific advice! If such a solution exists then yes, go ahead and use it. It's shorter, doesn't have memory issues and saves quite a bit of development time.

Comment: We are talking about the same SDK indeed! Loved this one, very specific but so simple!